# Version 2023.5.19 or later, Pipenv fails to recognize various Pythons installed on a Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, pipenv

I am using pipenv on Windows 10.

Since upgrading pipenv to v2023.5.19, it does not successfully recognize the version of Python installed on my PC.
It fails as follows.

```
PS > py -m pipenv --python 3.9
Warning: Python 3.9 was not found on your system...
Neither 'pyenv' nor 'asdf' could be found to install Python.
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
$ pipenv --python path\to\python
```

The path to each version of Python installed on the PC can be found from the `py` command.

```
PS > py --list-paths
 -V:3.11 *        [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
 -V:3.10          [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
 -V:3.9           [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
 -V:3.8           [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
 -V:3.7           [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

Therefore, as indicated in the error message, the virtual environment can be successfully created by specifying the Python path to be used.

```
> py -m pipenv --python [USERPROFILE]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
-> It's OK.
```

However, by simply downgrading pipenv to v2023.4.29, the above command succeeds as before.

```
PS > py -m pip install -U pipenv==2023.4.29

...

Successfully installed pipenv-2023.4.29

PS > py -m pipenv --python 3.9
Creating a virtualenv for this project...

...

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: [VENV PATH]
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
```

Is this problem a result of the changes made in the May update?
Also, do I need to specify the full path of the Python to be used each time in the future?

Comment: Probably you want to upvote my issue on Github: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5893. Since May versions `pipenv` only checks Python versions where the `../bin` directory is added to the `PATH` variable (which is expected behavior due to docs). I also expected it to work for older versions and felt it to be awkward that Py-Launcher is able to find all python versions and pipenv requires all installed python versions to be in the `PATH` (which I did not know in first place)